# Cannot 3D print prisms and ellipsoids

Tags: graphics3d

I get errors if I try to `Printout3D[ ]` or `Export[ ]` to an `.stl` file an object containing either an ellipsoid or prisms with any complexity. For example, neither:

```
testError = Graphics3D[{Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, .1], 
  Ellipsoid[{1, 1, .5}, {1, 1, .1}]}]
```

... nor

```
pos=20; top=.9; bottom=.1
testError=Graphics3D[
  Table[Prism[{{0, 0, top}, {1.2 Cos@x, 1.2 Sin@x,top},
 {1.2 Cos[x + 2 Pi/pos], 1.2 Sin[x + 2 Pi/pos], top}, {0, 0, bottom}, {1.2 Cos@x, 1.2 Sin@x,bottom}, {1.2 Cos[x + 2 Pi/pos], 1.2 Sin[x + 2 Pi/pos],bottom}}],
 {x, 0, 2 \[Pi] - 2 \[Pi]/pos, 5 2 \[Pi]/pos}]]
```

... produce the expected results with either `Export["test.stl",testError]` or `Pintout3D[testError,"test.stl"]`. What am I doing wrong? Using 12.1.

Comment: In the second one, the problem is you can't discretize a table of prisms inside a graphics. Instead, get rid of the `Graphics3D` and just have the table. You can display it later with Graphics3D[testError] and export / printout each one separately.

Comment: In the first one, you need to discretize it like this: `mesh = DiscretizeGraphics@
 Graphics3D[{Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, .1], 
   Ellipsoid[{1, 1, .5}, {1, 1, .1}]}]` but the tube will go missing.

Answer (score 3):

Just as @flinty mention,here we using `DiscretizeGraphics` and increasing the `MaxCellMeasure` for nonlinear model such `Tube` and `BezierSurface`.

```
mesh1 = DiscretizeGraphics[
  Graphics3D[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, .1]], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.01}]
mesh2 = 
  DiscretizeGraphics@Graphics3D[Ellipsoid[{1, 1, .5}, {1, 1, .1}]]
RegionUnion[mesh1, mesh2]
Export["combine.stl", %]
Import["combine.stl"]
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works with `Export[ ]` and successfully solves my problem. `Printout3D[ ]` continues to produce the same errors it did, but I now have a workaround. I don't understand why the plain solids do not work. Shouldn't they?